# Back - jQuery mobile and Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, vue.js, vuejs2

I have embedded a Vue component for a Activity Feed on a page inside a jQuery Mobile website.

The script loads 10 activities per request and adds them to the end of the list - triggered by scroll

If i click on a activity (for example "user added photo") it takes me to that user's profile. If I swipe back (on my phone) or hit back in browser it takes me back to the page and the feed reinitialises.

Any method for going back to the same state and to not being forced to load all the activities that were previously loaded and scroll to the specific one ?

Comment: You should take a look at [Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/)

Comment: If the activities are being loaded with an AJAX request you could always use LocalStorage or SessionStorage to cache the results of your AJAX request possible with a timer to invalidate it.

Comment: @no1xsyzy it's a jquery mobile website. not a vue one

Comment: @John no, it isn't, but vue router can help with that. although there introduces complexity. also, `localStorage` is good if you can script to load activities from `localStorage` first.

Comment: @John BTW, it is neither "problem" nor "bug", it is expected to perform like that: without router, the state of vue components don't persist within histories. so, either router or localStorage can help.

Comment: @John Oh, actually it is Vuex that persists state between histories. I've made a mistake.

Comment: @no1xsyzy it IS a jquery website. I only have a vue component running inside one page of the website. i'll try with localStorage tho

Comment: @John I meant "no, it isn't (a vue one)", anyway, it is good that `localStorage` can help